# SQL remove part of string

Tags: c#, sql-server

--- I went with a version of Andrey Gurinov's answer because I wanted to do in the query and he posted it first. ----

I have a database with names, addresses, city, state, zip, ect. for people. I want to read the data into a C# program in order of a group code, name, then a date. I am running into a problem though because a name has been entered in multiple ways by people.

Here is an example of the problem with a subset of the data:

```
| Dr. Kristen S   | 2011-04-15 00:00:00.000   | 00005573
| Kristen  S      | 2012-04-11 00:00:00.000   | 00005573
| Kristen S       | 2012-08-10 00:00:00.000   | 00005573
| Ms Kristen S    | 2011-08-12 00:00:00.000   | 00005573
| MS Kristen S    | 2012-01-27 00:00:00.000   | 00005573
| Ms. KRISTEN S   | 2012-04-09 00:00:00.000   | 00005573
```

As you can see, the name is relativly the same but the order of dates is not what I want. I want the dates in order.

If I read this data into my C# program is there a way to make the select statement recognize the variations (Dr. , MS , Ms. , Ms , "  " <- double space) and replace them with nothing or a single space? So that I can then sort the name groups by date. Or would I have I have to remove the variations permenately in the database.

----- EDIT (SQL Query) -----

```
SELECT  [ListMP]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Address1]
      ,[City]
      ,[State]
      ,[ZipCode]
      ,[Date]
      ,[OrderCode]
      ,[SequenceNbr]
  FROM [Customer].[dbo].[Orders]

  ORder by [OrderCode],[Name], [Date]
```

Sample output:

```
ORDER |Kristen S| 203 My Street| Bristol| RI| 02809| 2012-04-11 00:00:00.000| 05632| 00005573
```

The `OrderCode` is not unique to an individual, it's unique to an address where the address can have multiple people at.

Comment: Why not using a comboBox which contains the variations (Dr. , MS , Ms. , Ms ..) then sort them by date

Comment: What is this column? `00005573` If it's person id or something, then it will be easy.

Comment: Might you be willing to share your SQL query?  Does it have an `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: @Obama that is not something I want to do. I would rather do it one of the ways mentioned by myself or Nate said.

Comment: Some of the differences might be handled by [SOUNDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx?ppud=4).

Comment: @HABO I doubt it. That's something that sounds like it might be useful when you first hear of it but the algorithm is pretty useless in practice IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(name, 'Dr.', ''), 'Ms', ''), '  ', ' ') FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a little "name cleaner" procedure in c# that would strip these elements, and then sort the list by this stripped version and then by the date.  You could also perform this in the sql query side by a series of nested replaces.  Finally, as you mentioned, you could attempt to clean the entries in the database (possibly by creating another field for the cleaned name).

Which method you choose would be determined by how much data you are dealing with, and how often you need to do something like this.  If this is a lot of data, and you can see needing this in other future applications, I would recommend handling this at the database level.  You could write a function in SQL that formats the names, and then decide if you want to use it at query time or when inserting the data.

The function might look something like this:

```
drop function [fn_formatName]
go
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_formatName] 
(
    @Name nvarchar(4000)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    set @Name = replace(@Name, '.', '')
    set @Name = replace(@Name, '  ', ' ')

    if(len(@name) > 4) begin
        set @Name = replace(Left(@Name, 4), 'Mrs ', '') + Right(@Name, Len(@Name) - 4)
    end if(len(@name) > 4) begin
        set @Name = replace(Left(@Name, 4), 'Dr ', '') + Right(@Name, Len(@Name) - 4)
    end if(len(@name) > 4) begin
        set @Name = replace(Left(@Name, 4), 'Mr ', '') + Right(@Name, Len(@Name) - 4)
    end if(len(@name) > 4) begin    
        set @Name = replace(Left(@Name, 4), 'Ms ', '') + Right(@Name, Len(@Name) - 4)
    end

    set @Name = ltrim(@Name)

    RETURN @Name
END
```

And then your query would look like this

```
SELECT  [ListMP]
      ,[Name]
      ,dbo.fn_formatName([Name]) as 'CleanName',
      ,[Address1]
      ,[City]
      ,[State]
      ,[ZipCode]
      ,[Date]
      ,[OrderCode]
      ,[SequenceNbr]
  FROM [Customer].[dbo].[Orders]

  ORder by [OrderCode], CleanName, [Date]
```

Comment: So, when you say "use it at query time" what would that whole thing look like when I do my query in my C# program?

Comment: I updated the answer the the updated query using the function.  I would probably want to fix up this function a little, as it currently has the potential for incorrectly updating names that end in "mr" or "ms".

Comment: I updated the function as I wasn't too happy with my first attempt.  Feel free to clean it up a bit yourself as I'm not sure the performance is going to be that good as it is, but it should at least point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

you could use c# to clean up the name like so:

```
string FixedName(string name)
{
    name = name.Trim();
    var prefixes = new string[] { "Mrs. ", "Mrs ", "Mr. ", "Mr ", "Dr. ", "Dr " };
    foreach (var prefix in prefixes)
    {
        if (name.StartsWith(prefix, true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            name = name.Substring(prefix.Length).Trim();
            break;
        }
    }
    return name;
}
```